# Understanding Django's urlconf

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm trying to understand this line: `url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),` from [Django's tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/) on how to create views.

In particular, I don't understand the following:

- ?P
- \d+
- name='detail'

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `(?P<poll_id>...)` creates a [named group](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions); you can now refer to whatever was matched in that group by name.

  The view will be passed a keyword parameter by that name when called.
- `\d` is a character group, it matches numeric digits (`0` through to `9` for ASCII data). The `+` is a quantifier; only 1 or more digits will match.
- `name='detail'` names the URL pattern so you can refer to it by name later when creating reverse URLs. See [Naming URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) in the Django manual.

All in all, that pattern matches a URL that starts with digits, followed by just a `/` slash, causing Django to call the `views.detail` view, passing in the matched digits as the `poll_id` parameter. The `name` keyword makes it easy to generate a URL to this view:

```
{% url 'name' poll.id %}
```

would generate a URL to `http://yourserver/[digits of poll.id]/`.